# Sublime Text - pressing enter in search box creates a new line instead of searching

Tags: search, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

When I hit `ctrl+f`, then paste the searched phrase by `ctrl+v` and hit `enter` I expect the editor to Find the phrase, not to create another line in search box. Which is very irittating, since I have to manually click on the Find button. It happens now in Sublime Text 3 or program's linux version might be the case. How can I restore the proper behaviour?

Comment: Use tab instead of enter to finalize search.

Comment: tab creates indentation in search box

Comment: actually I think it selects the phrase as you type - if pasting, consider adding and deleting an extra character; the first occurance should be selected by default and you can reach every other by `ctrl+d` as I know

Comment: For me, testing in sublime text 2, if I paste the phrase in it tells me how many times it occurs. If i hit ENTER it selects the first occurrence, if i hit ENTER again it selects the second occurrence.  If the phrase contains a new line then it doesn't show it in the search box but it matches it if it can be matched. Suppose you type the phrase in (forget ctrl+v), is it not telling you how many times it occurs? And if you hit ENTER is it not matching the first occurrence?

Answer (score 11):

I'll bet you are using the enter key on the keypad (right side of the keyboard)

Add a key mapping like this to user key mappings:
Preferences -> Key Binding - User

```
{ "keys": ["keypad_enter"], "command": "find_next", "context":
        [{"key": "panel", "operand": "find"}, {"key": "panel_has_focus"}]
}
```

Source: http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/key_bindings.html

Comment: Indeed, Enter btn under the Backspace works as expected. Your advise helped to fix this 'issue' with Sublim on the macOS.

Answer (score 3):

In Sublime Text 4 it seems the behavior has changed again and makes `Enter` add a newline. I've found a way to fix it by adding this to the User Key Bindings:

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "find_all",
    "context": [{"key": "panel", "operand": "find_in_files"}, {"key": "panel_has_focus"}]
},
```

Comment: Had this happen on 1/18/2022 and this was the quick and easy resolution wth Sublime build 4126.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me too for sublime 4.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this behavior in Sublime Text 3, but only when pressing `Enter` while still holding down `Ctrl+V`. Are you sure you're not pressing `Enter` too quickly?

If you are copy/pasting text within Sublime Text 3, you can also highlight the text and press `Ctrl+F` to immediately paste the selection into the search box, and use `Enter` to search.

For reference, I'm using build 3059 on Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the wrap feature. This way the first occurrence will automatically be selected and hitting `Enter` should work as expected.

[image: wrap search sublime text]